# JSON Schema problems

Tags: json

I have quite a large JSON schema that I cant quite get to work.

It curently looks like this;

```json
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "AppAccessContext": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "CorrelationId": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "UniqueTokenId": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            },
            "CreationTime": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "Id": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "Operation": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "OrganizationId": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "RecordType": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "UserKey": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "UserType": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "Version": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "Workload": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "ClientIP": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "ObjectId": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "UserId": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "AuthenticationType": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "BrowserName": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "BrowserVersion": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "CorrelationId": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "DoNotDistributeEvent": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "EventSource": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "IsManagedDevice": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "ItemType": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "ListId": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "ListItemUniqueId": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "Platform": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "Site": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "UserAgent": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "WebId": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "DeviceDisplayName": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "HighPriorityMediaProcessing": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "ListBaseType": {
                "type": [
                    "number",
                    "string",
                    "integer"
                ]
            },
            "ListServerTemplate": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "SourceFileExtension": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "SiteUrl": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "SourceFileName": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "SourceRelativeUrl": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "FileSizeBytes": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "ApplicationDisplayName": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "ApplicationId": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "CustomUniqueId": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "EventData": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "MachineDomainInfo": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "MachineId": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "FileSyncBytesCommitted": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "ImplicitShare": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "CustomizedDoclib": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "FromApp": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "ItemCount": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "ListBaseTemplateType": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "ListColor": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "ListIcon": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "SkipForServiceWorker": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "Source": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "TemplateTypeId": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "ListTitle": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "SharingType": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "CrossScopeSyncDelete": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "DestinationFileExtension": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "DestinationFileName": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "DestinationRelativeUrl": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "SearchQueryText": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "CommentId": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "TargetUserOrGroupType": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "TargetUserOrGroupName": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "UniqueSharingId": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "AssertingApplicationId": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "ModifiedProperties": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "Name": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "NewValue": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    },
                    "required": [
                        "Name",
                        "NewValue"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "UserSessionId": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "ZipFileName": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "IsWorkflow": {
                "type": "boolean"
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "AppAccessContext",
            "CreationTime",
            "Id",
            "Operation",
            "OrganizationId",
            "RecordType",
            "UserKey",
            "UserType",
            "Version",
            "Workload",
            "ClientIP",
            "ObjectId",
            "UserId",
            "CorrelationId",
            "EventSource",
            "ItemType",
            "Site"
        ]
    }
}
```

Initially I had errors with 'ListBaseType' having multiple types.

Now I get the error;

```json
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Required properties are missing from object: ObjectId, Site.",
            "lineNumber": 0,
            "linePosition": 0,
            "path": "[703]",
            "value": [
                "ObjectId",
                "Site"
            ],
            "schemaId": "#/items",
            "errorType": "required",
            "childErrors": []
        },
```

Can anyone tell me what this means?

Comment: What's the JSON that you're validating? I believe the error message couldn't be much clearer. You are missing two property values (`ObjectId` and `Site`) which are required.

Comment: It's a huge json file about 10MB. 
Maybe I misunderstood the error, is it saying the JSON is missing object ID and site? There must be a few items that have those property values as null.

Comment: thanks. Fixed it by adding "null" to the peroperty. Misunderstanding on the error by me.